# Apache camel equivalent for spring @Transactional(readonly=true)

Tags: mysql, java-8, apache-camel, java-stream

I am trying to use Java Streams with JPA in Apache Camel Route with **MySQL**. I have seen few resources and they have mentioned that we need to have the below 3 properties for Streams to work properly with MySQL.
**1. Forward-only resultset
2. Read-only statement
3. Fetch-size set to Integer.MIN_VALUE**

I have tried setting the 2nd and 3rd property in the JPA Repository using QueryHint.

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true")
})
```

Looks like `Fetch-size` is working, but 2nd property is not working, as I am still facing the below error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@54b12700 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
```

I have made the route Transactional using `transacted()` which is equivalent to spring `@Transactional`. But not sure what is the equivalent for `@Transactional(readonly=true)`. Any leads?

```
from("direct:" + ROUTE_ID)
.routeId(ROUTE_ID)
.log("Start the processing")
.transacted()
.bean(Processor.class)
.to("log:ProcessName?showAll=true");
```

I have referred this [blog](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html) as reference.